# Sql server obtener todos los Ids sumados en select

Tags: sql-server

Hola tengo una consulta select donde sumo la cantidad en inventario y luego la multiplico por un costo, el problema es que para el ultimo_costo tengo que tomar el ultimo registro y tomar el costo de este, pero no simpre tiene costo y tengo que buscar en el registro anterior hasta encontrar uno con valor.

Para el ultimo registro no tengo problema uso esto

Material_Trans es el id de la tabla

```
select Unit_Cost from material_trans where material_trans = MAX(MT.MATERIAL_TRANS)
```

Pero aveces es 0 y no me sirve, no se si se pueda hacer algo como esto

```
select Unit_Cost from material_trans where material_trans IN Material_trans_list where Unit_Cost != 0 order by Material_Trans Desc
```

Pongo mi consulta sql

```
SELECT Material = M.Material,
  Descripcion = M.Description,
  Existencia = SUM(MT.Quantity),
  UdeM_Almacen = M.Stocked_UofM,
  Costo_Estandar = FORMAT(M.Standard_Cost * SUM(MT.Quantity), 'C', 'en-us'),
  Costo_Ultimo = FORMAT((select Unit_Cost from material_trans where material_trans = MAX(MT.MATERIAL_TRANS)) * SUM(MT.Quantity), 'C', 'en-us'),
  Costo_Promedio = FORMAT(AVG(MT.Unit_Cost) * SUM(MT.Quantity), 'C', 'en-us'),
  Costo_Promedio_Ponderado = FORMAT(CASE WHEN SUM(MT.Quantity) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(MT.Quantity*MT.Unit_Cost)/SUM(MT.Quantity) END, 'C', 'en-us'),
  UdeM_Costo = M.Cost_UofM
FROM Material_Trans MT
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT COALESCE(MT.Material, MR.Material, S.Material, J.Part_Number, SD.Material) AS Material
FROM Material_Trans IMT
  LEFT JOIN Source S ON S.Source = IMT.Source
  LEFT JOIN Material_Req MR ON MR.Material_Req = S.Material_Req OR MR.Material_Req = IMT.Material_Req
  LEFT JOIN Job_Operation JO ON JO.Job_Operation = S.Job_Operation
  LEFT JOIN Job J ON J.Job = JO.Job
  LEFT JOIN SO_Detail SD ON SD.SO_Detail = IMT.SO_Detail
WHERE IMT.Material_Trans = mt.Material_Trans
)AS Mat
INNER JOIN Material M ON M.Material = Mat.Material --Solo materiales que existan en material
    WHERE 
    MT.Tran_Type NOT IN ('Invoice', 'LocTfr') 
    AND MT.Quantity != 0
    AND Vendor_Trans IS NULL
    AND CAST(MT.Material_Trans_Date AS DATE) <= '2019-10-15'
GROUP BY M.Material, M.Description, M.Stocked_UofM, M.Cost_UofM, M.Cost_UofM, M.Last_Cost, M.Average_Cost, M.Standard_Cost
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: select Unit_Cost from material_trans where material_trans = (select MAX(MT.MATERIAL_TRANS) where costo >0)

Comment: Hola, me sale Null si hago eso :(

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar alias de tablas y en el diseño de las tablas usar nombre de columnas con buenas practicas

```
SELECT 
    Material = M.Material,
    Descripcion = M.Description,
    Existencia = SUM(MT.Quantity),
    UdeM_Almacen = M.Stocked_UofM,
    Costo_Estandar = FORMAT(M.Standard_Cost * SUM(MT.Quantity), 'C', 'en-us'),
    Costo_Ultimo = FORMAT(ISNULL(TUC.Unit_Cost, 0) * SUM(MT.Quantity), 'C', 'en-us'),
    Costo_Promedio = FORMAT(AVG(MT.Unit_Cost) * SUM(MT.Quantity), 'C', 'en-us'),
    Costo_Promedio_Ponderado = FORMAT(CASE WHEN SUM(MT.Quantity) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(MT.Quantity*MT.Unit_Cost)/SUM(MT.Quantity) END, 'C', 'en-us'),
    UdeM_Costo = M.Cost_UofM
FROM 
    Material_Trans MT
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(MT.Material, MR.Material, S.Material, J.Part_Number, SD.Material) AS Material
        FROM Material_Trans IMT
            LEFT JOIN Source S ON S.Source = IMT.Source
            LEFT JOIN Material_Req MR ON MR.Material_Req = S.Material_Req OR MR.Material_Req = IMT.Material_Req
            LEFT JOIN Job_Operation JO ON JO.Job_Operation = S.Job_Operation
            LEFT JOIN Job J ON J.Job = JO.Job
            LEFT JOIN SO_Detail SD ON SD.SO_Detail = IMT.SO_Detail
        WHERE IMT.Material_Trans = MT.Material_Trans
    )AS Mat
    INNER JOIN Material M ON M.Material = Mat.Material --Solo materiales que existan en material
    LEFT JOIN (     
        SELECT 
             Z.Material,
             Z.MATERIAL_TRANS,
             Z.Unit_Cost
        FROM 
            Material_Trans Z WITH(NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT 
                     A.Material,
                     MAX(MATERIAL_TRANS) MATERIAL_TRANS      
                FROM 
                    Material_Trans A WITH(NOLOCK)
                WHERE
                    A.Unit_Cost > 0
                GROUP BY
                    A.Material
            ) Y ON Z.MATERIAL_TRANS = Y.MATERIAL_TRANS
    ) TUC ON TUC.Material = M.Material
WHERE 
    MT.Tran_Type NOT IN ('Invoice', 'LocTfr') 
    AND MT.Quantity != 0
    AND Vendor_Trans IS NULL
    AND CAST(MT.Material_Trans_Date AS DATE) <= '2019-10-15'
GROUP BY 
    M.Material, 
    M.Description, 
    M.Stocked_UofM, 
    M.Cost_UofM, 
    M.Cost_UofM, 
    M.Last_Cost, 
    M.Average_Cost, 
    M.Standard_Cost
```